# Convergence of Difference of Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \infty$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} = q.$$ What can we say about $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n-y_nq?$$

What conditions can we put on $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ to get the limit of $0$?

Answer (score 2):

Anything can happen - you might get lucky and have the second limit be 0, but not always. For example, consider $x_n=n^2+n$ and $y=n^2$. We have that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n}=1$ but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n-y_n=\infty$.

Comment: What extra conditions can we put on the sequences to have the limit be 0?